# Project won't compile, file is green in SVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn

My project won't compile in visual studio because it can't find/copy a file named bootstrap.js to the obj/ folder. When I go in the folder via the file explorer I noticed the file name is green. I am not sure if it is a coincidence, but I wonder if finding the root cause of the green file could fix my issue.

[image]

Comment: Compilation error will be helpful.

Comment: File is encrypted by Windows NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was having the file being "Encrypted". Right-click on the file properties, go in "Adavanced" and uncheck the box highlighted.

[image]